# .NET System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

We are connecting to a specific website using a TLS connection. We are enforcing TLS 1.2 as the only allowed protocol in the client code. In about 99% of all cases connection setup is OK and shows no errors. However from time to time we receive the following exception:

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The buffers supplied to a function was too small
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
>          at Fw.Connections.Ssl.Private.ClientInstance.AuthenticateClientCallback(IAsyncResult result);

We have tested the remote server with SSL labs and we receive an A+ with no failures or problems reported, it's not a server under our control so the remote environment is not very well known.. We have tested the client code on Windows server 2012 (datacenter) and Windows7 clients. Both show the error from time to time. Is this a known bug in the .NET framework?

Comment: Could this be due to a server memory limitation? Having "buffers" that are "too small" might imply this.

Comment: No, this is a very unlikely reason. The server has plenty of free memory.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1854#issuecomment-160513245